# "Ich habe dich akustisch nicht verstanden"

Tags: meaning, usage

I have heard many people using the expression

> "Ich habe dich akustisch nicht verstanden"

which strikes me as very convoluted (my mother tongue is Italian, but I speak English on a regular basis). What I feel would be natural to say in such circumstances is

> "Ich habe dich nicht richtig gehört"

because it seems like a redundancy to specify the way you did not understand something which has been said. On top of that, I was wondering if "verstehen" doesn't itself already imply a deeper understanding of the actual meaning of what's being said. If it did, this would make the expression inexact.
So, what I am wondering here is:

- how natural does this sentence sound to a native speaker?
- how correct is it from a linguistic point of view?

Comment: The *akustisch* is in there exactly because otherwise, as you suggest, *verstehen* might be understood to refer to the meaning. Nevertheless your *Ich habe dich nicht richtig gehört* might be preferable.

Comment: My personal opinion as a native speaker: The accepted answer is correct. But: _akustisch nicht verstanden_ came up as a convoluted way of saying _I habe Dich nicht (richtig) gehört_ towards the late 90s (from what I recall; [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=akustisch+nicht+verstanden&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3) puts it much earlier). Some people mixed it up and said _Das habe ich jetzt akustisch nicht gehört_, which is of course redundant. Sticking with _Ich habe Dich nicht richtig gehört_ is fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is quite common to say `akustisch nicht verstanden` in contrast to `inhaltlich nicht verstanden`. The alternative would be `nicht richtig gehört`.

Some native speakers might regard `akustisch nicht verstanden` as unnatural preferring `nicht richtig gehört`. For others it's the opposite.

From a linguistic point of view, it's correct. It's a partial translation of

> Ich habe dich *bezüglich des Hörens* nicht verstanden.

or

> Ich habe dich nicht verstanden *, weil ich dich nicht gehört habe.*

Comment: So having _akustisch_ as an adverb for _verstehen_ makes sense?

Comment: @ashlotte It does, it's what people say here.

Comment: That is highly irrelevant, people say nonsense all the time everywhere ^.^

Comment: @ashlotte "akustisch" is very fundamental here, as otherwise people might start explaining what they meant while you actually just wanted them to repeat. There are indeed alternatives, like just explicitly saying that someone should repeat or explaining why you didn't hear them ('you speak too quietly') but the phrase in question has definitely gained most popularity amongst all of them.

Comment: I understand why it may be necessary, what I am unsure about is if it is exact: I wonder if _verstehen_ can be correctly used referring to acoustic comprehension or is exclusive to interpretation.

Comment: @ashlotte... it can be used either way.... "Der Mann war schwer zu verstehen."... meaning "it was hard to hear what he was saying", "Das Thema ist schwer zu verstehen." Meaning... comprehend intelectually. It works both way, thus adding an adverb to specify which way you are referring to is just natural

Comment: My source would be [this](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verstehen), where I can read one of the definitions of _verstehen_ is  _deutlich_ _akustisch_ _wahrnehmen_. However it appears to just be acceptable in spoken German. Nevertheless I have no clue about the reliability of German online dictionaries out there.

Comment: @ashlotte... wiktionary is usually pretty accurate. As usual best is to check different sources and see how they intersect. Anyway, you question is answered now, is it? (I feel like you're still not convinced)

Comment: @ashlotte: What makes you think that this definition is specific to the spoken language?

Comment: The definition I mentioned _deutlich akustisch wahrnehmen_ has a _(Gesprochenes)_ written at the start, so I assume that stands for "spoken", as in just correct in spoken German.

Comment: @ashlotte Well, the point is that it only make sense in spoken language. It doesn't make any sense in written language. For that reason, it's use in restricted to spoken language. That's what they meant.

Comment: @Em1 Either it is possible to "acoustically understand" something or it is not. That is what is not cleat to me. I understand that the usage of verstehen referring to the hearing is widely spread and accepted in spoken language and that the expression itself is grammatical. Nevertheless, _verstehen_ seems to be bound to the meaning of something, not the "sound". That is why I wonder if the expression isn't somehow inexact, even if grammatical.

Comment: @ashlotte Eventually, I looked it up myself. "(Gesprochenes)" in Wiktionary does not indicate that it only appears in spoken language. I guess it would be more clear what they meant if it were "(Gesprochenes, Geflüstertes, Gerufenes, ...) deutlich akustisch wahrnehmen". The definition is actually just "akustisch wahrnehmen" and "Gesprochenes" is what it usually refers to. DWDS defines it as "**wahrnehmen**, begreifen, geistig erfassen, etw. beherrschen, **deutlich hören**"; those in bold refer to acoustic perception. I checked a few bilingual dictionaries and they fail to get the point clear.

Comment: @ashlotte Sorry, that I didn't looked it up in the first place, so my previous comment an hour ago might be a little confusing. Although it's technically correct what I said, it's not fitting to the Wiktionary definition.

Comment: @Em1 yeah that is exactly what I was referring to, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> Ich habe dich akustisch nicht verstanden.

This is quite a common formula. The reason for not understanding may be loud noise from outside.

> Ich verstehe nicht, was du meinst.

This would be a formula when you don't understand the meaning of the person you talk with.

> Ich hab wohl nicht richtig gehört!

This is a harsh critique. You express the idea that what you heard is impolite or nasty.

Answer (score 1):

I see the reason in

> "It's not what you say, but how you say it."

That said, when I grew up, the common reply was:

> Ich habe Dich nicht gehört.

The problem occures with any nonverbal gestures and verbal emphasis/ stressing/ intonation:

- you could mean there was an accustic problem.
- you could mean there was a problem in regard of content (you understand the words, but they make no sense to you)
- you could mean there was a problem in regard of situation (you understand the words, you understand a meaning of the sentence, they just don't fit into the circumstances)
- you could mean you did not *want* to hear the words - like "What you don't know won't hurt you./ What the eye doesn't see, the heart doesn't grieve over."
- you could mean that - especially when someone asks you something - you want to have another way of communication,

  - like "beg me"
  - like "I will never listen to you until I got forced"
  - like "my ego forbids me to communicate about the topic with *you*, so find a way around"

That answer "ich hab Dich nicht gehört" has also different wordings which could fit (regarding relationship of speakers) to interpretations mentioned above:

- Häh?
- Wie bitte?
- Was war das?
- Nochmal!
- Hm?
- Ich habe Dich nicht verstanden.
- Kannst Du das nochmal sagen?
- Wie meinen?
- Ich habe Dich nicht richtig gehört.

As you might figure out, with a fitting verbal & nonverbal expression these replies could be anything like

- mean
- sarcastic
- friendly
- short
- acustic problem
- content problem
- wording problem
- context problem
- etc.

That is my observation, why people started to say

> Ich habe Dich akustisch nicht verstanden.

to emphasize exactly and only this reason for a lack of a better fitting answer.